# Can't get rid of the text indentation within inline blockquote

Tags: html, css, blockquote

I have a blockquote displayed as inline element.
My text get indentation in the first line and I can't remove it.
As you can see I have been tried to use `margin:0` `padding:0` `text-indent:0`

```css
blockquote {
    display:inline;
    background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
}

blockquote::first-line {
  margin:0 !important;
  padding:0 !important;
  text-indent:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>Some text Some text Some text Some text<br>some othersome other some other some other some other</blockquote>
```

Comment: margin:0 should be applied on the element not the first line

Comment: @TemaniAfif I feel stupid... Thanks